# How to resolve "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" error in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack-dev-server

I am learning javascript and in order to do so, I am configuring webpack on a new project.
When I run the "webpack script"(in the package.json) it works correctly, but it does not work with the "start script". And I got this error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE". I tested some solutions(1.npm cache clean --force, 2.delete package.json and node modules 3.npm install, npm start) seen on this forum but still does not work.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "todoProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.html")
    })
  ],
  stats: "minimal",
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    open: false,
    contentBase: "./dist",
    inline: true,
    port: 4000
  }
};
```

The Error:

```
> webpack-dev-server

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dem\Documents\dymaProject\todoProject\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\demil\Documents\dymaProject\todoProject\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\dem\\Documents\\dymaProject\\todoProject\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todoProject@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todoProject@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\demil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-22T0T05_36_55_879Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with npm :

```sh
npm start
```

Not

```sh
webpack-dev-server
```

maybe `webpack-cli` is not installed globally ?

Comment: yes, I do run my script with npm start or npm run start. In package.json, there is webpack-cli, so I think it is globally install right?

Comment: No every package inside your package.json is installed locally to your project. This is why I asked you if you run npm start or using the global package webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Okay, so how do I install it globally?

Comment: npm install -g webpack-dev-server